# How can I pass a float value to a class that extends LinearLayout before it gets inflated?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created a class that extends `LinearLayout` to draw a border-radius and added the `setRadius()` function

```
public class RadiusLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
private float CORNER_RADIUS;

private Bitmap maskBitmap;
private Paint paint, maskPaint;
private float cornerRadius;

public void setRadius(float cornerRadius) {
    CORNER_RADIUS = cornerRadius;
}


public RadiusLinearLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null, 0);
}

public RadiusLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs, 0);
}

public RadiusLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

    super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

    if (maskBitmap == null) {
        maskBitmap = createMask(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);
}

private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {
    Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

    return mask;
}
```

}

On the fragment that corresponds to this class, `OnCreateView` I refence the `Layout` and set the radius value but it doesn't apply the value I send to the layout

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calculator_fragment, container, false)

     val test = view.findViewById(R.id.testCF) as RadiusLinearLayout
    test.setRadius(2f)

    return view
}
```

Is it possible to pass a value to the `Layout` before the fragment gets inflated?

Comment: You should use your logic from init block in the setRadius method. Right now you are setting cornerRadius only once in init and then set the CORNER_RADIUS instead. You can also prepare xml attribute for cornerRadius and use it in xml file where you are using your custom view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass a value to the Layout before the fragment gets inflated?

Basically yes (*), but I'd like to show how to change the radius of your custom `View` more flexibly:

There are certain changes to a `View` which make it necessary to update the UI, for example if you call `View.setBackground()`.

In such cases, the `View` calls `invalidate()` to let the runtime know that it needs to be redrawn.

Your custom `View` can do so each time the radius is set:

```
public void setRadius(float cornerRadius) {
    CORNER_RADIUS = cornerRadius;

    // Now you need to calculate the field *cornerRadius* once more
    //
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

    invalidate();
}
```

By the way, setting the corner radius to 2f does not cause that much of a change - I tried with 24f, and it worked fine.

(*) If you absolutely need to change the radius before the custom `View` is inflated, you can either create it programmatically and call `setRadius()` before adding it to a `ViewGroup`.
Or you [define a custom attribute](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr) to configure the `View` via the layout file.

Comment: Thank you for answering but after trying this method I still can't get it to work. I also tried calling the invalidate function programmatically after the view has been created  with no luck

Comment: @Ever - you are right, there was something else still missing (*cornerRadius* has to be updated if CORNER_RADIUS changes), please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: It seems you have declared same name of a variable cornerRadius which is declared globally and parameter of setradius method. It created ambiguity. Change the parameter name and do a try.

Something like this

```
private float cornerRadius;

public void setRadius(float radius) {
    CORNER_RADIUS = radius;
}
```

Solution 2: Pass corner radius value by its constructor

```
Example:

public RadiusLinearLayout(Context context,float radius) {
    super(context);
    CORNER_RADIUS = radius;
    init(context, null, 0);
}
```